# How to draw smooth lines with thickness in OpenGL [ES 2]

Tags: opengl-es, drawing, opengl-es-2.0

I'm looking for a way to draw lines with thickness and smoothness with OpenGL ES2 without using the build it glLineWidth function which has a lot of limitations. I think this can be done using shaders, but my glsl skills are limited.

What I've already tried is to actually construct a poly with rounded joints like in this [question's answer](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/28883/render-a-polyline-with-rounded-joints). However, for my purpose of free drawing this is an overkill and makes my app run very slow. So, I'm thinking, doing the same in the vertex shader will increase the performance, but not that much to become usable for my purpose (drawing).

So, right now I have a set of points that would describe the line nicely, if I would be able to connect them and give each connected segment thickness.

Comment: The shader doing what you want would need to be the **geometry** shader rather than vertex shader (you want to construct vertices based on the data given).

Comment: As far as I know (I might be wrong) there are 2 types of shaders (vertex shaders and fragment shaders). The first works with vertices and the second with fragments, which are "points" interpolated between 2 vertices.

Comment: There are **four** types of shaders. Geometry, Tesselation, Vertex and Fragment. At least in new OpenGL. Take a look at [GLSL Standard](http://www.opengl.org/registry/doc/GLSLangSpec.4.20.6.clean.pdf)

Comment: The title and tags for the question said OpenGL ES 2: there are only 2 shaders (vertex and fragment), as Valentin commented correctly.

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz And even for modern desktop GL that is plain wrong (though *Peter* and *Valentin* are absolutely correct anyway). There are *five* types of shaders, vertex, tessellation control, tessellation evaluation, geometry and fragment.

Comment: @ChristianRau thanks for reminding me of my shortcomings from september last year :)

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz How should I know you have overcome those already? ;) And in the end anybody could read this post (especially since it's recently active again) and get some very wrong ideas from the comments. An old wrong statement is still a wrong statement if not corrected.

Answer (score 1):

What's often done in this case is to draw a quad with no smoothing. Then draw the outline of the quad using smooth, single-pixel wide line drawing.